# PHP Won't echo same code in different div

Tags: php, html, echo

This part of the code works fine:

```
    <div id="Vraag">
    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
        {
            echo $row["vraag"];
        }
    ?>
    </div>
```

But this part does not work:

```
    <div id="antAA">
     <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
        {
            echo $row["AntwA"];
        }
        ?>
        <!-- <a href="#" id="antAA">Antwoord A</a> -->
    </div>
```

And I have no idea why it is not working. It is the same code. The database works fine because if I run this code all the way in the the top of my code it echoes all of them fine:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
 {
  echo $row["id"];
  echo $row["vraag"];
  echo $row["AntwA"];
  echo $row["AntwB"];
  echo $row["AntwC"];
  echo $row["AntwD"];
 }
```

But in the div it just does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="se.css">
    <title>Lotto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "lotto";
    $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    $query = "SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD,id FROM vraag1";
    $rows = mysqli_query($db, $query);


    // while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
    // {
    //  echo $row["id"];
    //  echo $row["vraag"];
    //  echo $row["AntwA"];
    //  echo $row["AntwB"];
    //  echo $row["AntwC"];
    //  echo $row["AntwD"];
    // }

    ?>
    <div id="headerbg"></div>
    <center>
        <h1>Vraag 1</h1>
    </center>
    <center>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img6">
        </div>
        <div id="Vraag">
        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
            {
                echo $row["vraag"];
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <div id="plaatje">
            <img id="img1" src="wip.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="BGantA">
            <img id="img2" src="antw.png">
        </div>

        <div id="antAA">
         <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
            {
                echo $row["vraag"];
            }
            ?>
            <!-- <a href="#" id="antAA">Antwoord A</a> -->
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antBB">Antwoord B</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antCC">Antwoord C</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antDD">Antwoord D</a>
        </div>

    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code if needed:

```
body{
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;

     /*#ECECEC;*/
}
#headerbg{
    display: block;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    width: 102%;
    height: 118px;
    background-color: #333333;
    /*#232323;*/
}
h1{
    font-family: times;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -800px;
    margin-top:-76px;
    color: #979797; 
}
#img2, #img3, #img4, #img5{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    display: block;
}
img{
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 5px;
}
#img1{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#img2{
    margin-top: -370px;
    margin-left: -800px;
}
#img3{
    margin-top:-67px;
    margin-left:800px;
}
#img4{
    margin-left:-800px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
#img5{
    margin-left: 800px;
    margin-top: -67px;
}
#img6{
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: ;
}
#antAA, #antBB, #antCC, #antDD{
    display: block;
    /*color: #979797;*/
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#antAA, #antCC{
    margin-top: -65px;
    margin-right: 800px;
}
#antBB{
    margin-top: -65px;
    margin-left: 800px;
}
#antDD{
    margin-left: 800px;
    margin-top:-65px;
}
#Vraag{
    display:block;
    color: red; 
    margin-top: -44px;
}
#antAA:hover, #antBB:hover, #antCC:hover, #antDD:hover{
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: submit what you are trying....the entire code here your problem is not dectectable..

Comment: you are looping twice over the query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

mysqli_data_seek($rows, 0);

After every while loop.
This sets the counter back to 0

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="se.css">
    <title>Lotto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "lotto";
    $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    $query = "SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD,id FROM vraag1";
    $rows = mysqli_query($db, $query);


    // while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
    // {
    //  echo $row["id"];
    //  echo $row["vraag"];
    //  echo $row["AntwA"];
    //  echo $row["AntwB"];
    //  echo $row["AntwC"];
    //  echo $row["AntwD"];
    // }

    ?>
    <div id="headerbg"></div>
    <center>
        <h1>Vraag 1</h1>
    </center>
    <center>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img6">
        </div>
        <div id="Vraag">
        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
            {
                echo $row["vraag"];
            }
            mysqli_data_seek($rows, 0);
        ?>
        </div>
        <div id="plaatje">
            <img id="img1" src="wip.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="BGantA">
            <img id="img2" src="antw.png">
        </div>

        <div id="antAA">
         <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
            {
                echo $row["vraag"];
            }
            mysqli_data_seek($rows, 0);
            ?>
            <!-- <a href="#" id="antAA">Antwoord A</a> -->
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antBB">Antwoord B</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antCC">Antwoord C</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="antw.png" id="img5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="antDD">Antwoord D</a>
        </div>

    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you execute `mysqli_fetch_assoc` then it return false as last value has been fetched and has no further value.

If you want to use this for multiple times you can save its value in array and then use this array

```
<?php
  $vraag_array=array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
            {
                 $vraag_array[] = $row["vraag"];
            }

           //to echo
      // close     
      ?>
        <div id="Vraag">
    <?php
        foreach ($vraag_array as $vraag_value) {
                   echo vraag_value;
           }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="plaatje">
        <img id="img1" src="wip.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="BGantA">
        <img id="img2" src="antw.png">
    </div>

    <div id="antAA">
     <?php
        foreach ($vraag_array as $vraag_value) {
                   echo vraag_value;
           }
        ?>
        <!-- <a href="#" id="antAA">Antwoord A</a> -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure. But I think this is because in the first while loop it takes out the "vraag".

So in the second while loop, it may think its the same loop so there is no more data to display there. Try to put in the query again right above the second loop. With other variable names

```
 $query2 = "SELECT id, vraag, AntwA, AntwB, AntwC, AntwD,id FROM vraag1";
 $rows2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2); 

 while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're iterating through and fetching all the rows, but only reading out the one that matches "vraag". When you execute a second time, you have already iterated through and exhausted all the rows.

That's why this bit works:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
 {
  echo $row["id"];
  echo $row["vraag"];
  echo $row["AntwA"];
  echo $row["AntwB"];
  echo $row["AntwC"];
  echo $row["AntwD"];
 }
```

Because you're using each row as it is being processed over.

I can't really understand why you're executing such code, which iterates over entire collections and reads out the same singular value each time, but if you want the second attempt to work, you will have to execute this line again:

```
$rows = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Definitely consider rethinking the entire structure though.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use different `variables` for different `values`. Please try different `variable name` in next code which is not working, just like this:

```
<div id="antAA">
     <?php
     while($row_new = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
     {
         echo $row_new["AntwA"];
     }
     ?>
     <!-- <a href="#" id="antAA">Antwoord A</a> -->
</div>
```

I hope, this will solve your issue.